# How to key string of user IDs to user objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting, next.js

I'm trying to implement a "pin this profile" feature to my website.  My idea was to collect an  array of string with the user IDs of the individual whom I want to pin (completed successfully), and then push those IDs to the top of the list of profiles (having issues with this).

The problem I'm having this - how can I key the string of user IDs (`pinTutors`) to the correct user objects (`tutors`), so I can sort the user objects accordingly?  The user IDs are currently in the form of strings, I got them through using `props.tutor.id`.  And the user objects are just typical objects with all the users data in them, including their ID.  But I'm not sure how to sort that list of objects based on my array of strings, if that makes sense.

Here's my attempt (logic for sorting is not correct):

```
export default function Index(props: {tutor: tutor, Student: Student}) {

const auth = useAuth();
const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([]);
const [filterTutors, setFilterTutors] = useState<tutor[]>(null);
const [tutors, setTutors] = useState<tutor[]>(null);
const [prices, setPrices] = useState<number[]>(possiblePrices);
const [pinTutor, setPinTutor] = useState<Student["pins"]>([]);   

useEffect(() => {
    get("tutor/list").then(res => {
        setTutors(res.data);
        setFilterTutors(res.data);
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.authLoaded && auth.authState === "signedIn") { postInfo(); }
    function postInfo(e = null) {
        const userId = e ? e.detail.user_id : auth.userInfo.user_id;
        get(`client/get/${userId}`, { _id: userId }, { "pins": pinTutor }, auth).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(pinTutor);
            setFilterTutors(filterByStar(tutors));
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
        });
        for(let i=0; i>tutors.length; i++){
            setFilterTutors(filterByStar(tutors));
        }
    }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (tutors) {
        if (!subjects || subjects.length === 0) {
            setFilterTutors(filterByPrice(tutors));
        } else if (!pinTutor || pinTutor.length === 0) {
            setFilterTutors(filterByStar(tutors));
        } else {
            console.log(subjects);
            console.log(tutors);
            setFilterTutors(filterByPrice(tutors.filter(tutor => subjects.some(subject => (tutor.subjects && tutor.subjects.includes(subject.value))))));
        }
    }
}, [subjects, prices, tutors]);

function filterByPrice(arr){
    return arr.filter(tutor => prices.some(price => tutor.price === price));
}

function filterByStar(arr){
    props.tutor.id.map(pinTutor);
    return arr.unshift(pinTutor);
}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function Tutor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.props = "";
}

let arrTutors = []; // array of tutors (objects)

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // now we have tutors with IDs from "0" to "19"
    arrTutors.push(new Tutor(i.toString()));
}

let pinTutors = ["0", "7", "13", "18"]; // let's pin tutors with these IDs

let filteredArrTutors = []; // we will have objects with IDs from pinTutors array here

pinTutors.forEach((tutorID) => {
    filteredArrTutors.push(arrTutors.find(tutor => tutor.id === tutorID));
});

// now we have in the filteredArrTutors array objects with IDs "0", "7", "13", and "18"
```